# Exclude entity from NSPersistentDocument

Tags: core-data, nspersistentdocument

I have an existing (and fully working) app using `NSPersistentDocument` to save the application files.
Now I need to create a new entity, this new entity is totally unrelated to the application files and it will contain the application cache, so I will use it to save on a separated file.
My project contains the `MyDocument.xcdatamodeld` used by `NSPersistentDocument`, to implement the new feature I created a new data model `Cache.xcdatamodeld` and added a new entity to the model (I have not written code just used XCode wizards) but when I run the app and try to open an existing app file I receive the error

> The model used to open the store is incompatible with the one used to
>   create the store

I understand this occurs because the model configuration for new entity is the same for `NSPersistentDocument` but how can I decouple it?
Creating a new configuration in data model doesn't work because the entity can't be deleted from the default one.
Any idea how to make `NSPersistentDocument` ignore the new entity and continue to work with the old data model?

I don't post source code because this happens simply adding the new model and entity to project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [NSPersistDocument's `managedObjectModel` property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPersistentDocument_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSPersistentDocument/managedObjectModel):

> `@property(readonly, strong) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel`
>
> Discussion
>
> By default the Core Data framework creates a merged model from all models in the application bundle ([NSBundle mainBundle]). You can reimplement this property and return a specific model to use to create persistent stores. A typical implementation might include code similar to the following fragment:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"MyModel" ofType:@"mom"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSManagedObjectModel *model = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Wow I totally missed the api description, it works fine, thanks!